# 27.5 x 1.95 tyres what sizes can i change to

Tags: tire

what other size tyres can i fit to these wheels? As I can only find mtb tyres and want to put a road tyre on? something faster with less tread

Comment: How wide is the rim?  Preferably in millimeters, inside the walls(basically, where the tire seats)?

Comment: You can find slick tires in most diameters. Look also under 650b for slicks.

Comment: 650bx32 or 35mm should be smaller (around 1.5-1.75") 650b is the "road" naming convention for this wheel diameter. but as mentioned above, you can only go so small on a rim (usually about 1.5-2x internal width)

Answer (score 1):

I manage a fleet of 150 MTB's that are used on city streets. The original knobby tires  wear down quickly. I replace them with Serfas Drifter City tires. These have three advantages: an inverted, long-wearing tread; built-in puncture resistance and more economical than the Schawlbes I run on my personal bike. They come in several sizes.